# debugging code with menhir and ocamlbuild

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, menhir

I am implementing a small programming language. Here is the [codebase](https://github.com/zzehli/PicoProlog). The program is built with `ocamlbuild`. I added a parser using `menhir`. When I compile and run the program, I got the following message.

```
❱ ./main.byte 
Fatal error: exception Parser.MenhirBasics.Error
```

I am trying to find more details by passing the `explain` to the `_tag` file

```
true: color(always), explain
```

but there doesn't seem to be any difference. How to I make `menhir` to generate a logging file through ocamlbuild? or other ways to debug?

Comment: You can get a stack trace by running `ocamlrun -b main.byte`, which might point to something useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is syntax error raised by the parser generated by menhir.

Your build system is irrelevant (nevertheless, you should use `dune` for a new project and not `ocamlbuild`).

Similarly, the `--explain` flag of `menhir` is only useful for generating conflict explanations when generating the parser. It doesn't add syntax error explanation to syntax error.

If you want to debug a menhir grammar, you can use menhir intepreter mode with `menhir --interpret`

```sh
menhir --interpret parser.mly
```

or list all possible syntax errors in your grammar with `menhir --list-errors`.

```sh
menhir --list-errors parser.mly
```

Both options should make the reason why `"hi." is a syntax error in your grammar relatively clear.

Comment: Thanks. I am having trouble figuring out how to pass those flags to `menhir` through `ocamlbuild` since they are tool-specific commands. It seems I have to write a `myocamlbuild` file to introduce those commands like [this](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlbuild/blob/master/manual/manual.adoc#flag-declarations)?

Comment: You should call `menhir` on your `parser.mly` file directly, since it is more a question of analyzing your grammar than something that should be part of the regular build process. I edited the answer to mention this.